# How to reset default DNS settings on OS X High Sierra?

Tags: macos, dns, dhcp

Every time I connect to some public WiFi hotspot, and sometimes when I'm using something familiar, like my home one, DNS servers are set to 8.8.8.8. This is annoying on some public WiFi, because some of them blocks all traffic (including DNS requests to 8.8.8.8) until I enter some auth information on their login page or watch an ad or whatever, and their system expects that my laptop uses DNS server provided by their DHCP server. So I have to go to DNS tab in "Advanced Settings" of wifi interface in network preferences, then click "-" on a lone 8.8.8.8 server in the list, after that immediately appear two new DNS servers provided by the router.

Looks like I somehow set 8.8.8.8 in the past as my default DNS for that interface, and it takes precedence above DHCP settings, and that default is restored on every reconnect to wifi. But how I did that? I've tried everything in GUI, grepped through /etc, maybe there's some plist somewhere I have to edit (again)?

Comment: What version of OS X are you using?  Edit your question

Comment: High Sierra. I've edited title.

Comment: It sounds like removing 8.8.8.8 in Advanced Settings fixes the problem temporarily, but then it reappears; is this correct? If so, it's almost certainly some piece of software installed on your Mac that's resetting it. What do you have installed that might be dealing with network settings (VPN, things like that)? Does the problem's reappearance correlate to anything you do/run on the Mac?